# Which is the best way to store a pdf around ~4mb in sqlite with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, base64, offline-storage

Which is the best way to store a pdf around ~4mb in sqlite with javascript?

I have tried using base 64 encoding but the Andoid browser freezes and quits when trying to open large files. Small files won't open either they just start to download but the download never completes and the filetype seems to be unknown. It has to work in the Android browser, and I have several files that I need to save so I have to use sqlite (because of size limits in offline storage)

Thanks in advance!
/Christian

Comment: why do you want a 4MB pdf in sqlite? it cannot be modified and cannot interact with javascript. what's the point of storing a binary file? and when you say store, store from where to sqlite?

Comment: I want to store it in sqlite because the files has to be available for users offline like the rest of the web application is. I can't use localstorage because of size limitation of 5 mb, I can't access FS with javascript. I don't want all users to have to download all pdf files manually to the file system. Which options do you think I have left except sqlite?

Comment: Isn't the SQLite database included in the offline storage quota of 5MB?

Comment: @ChristianV: here is the thing, if you stored the file successfully in sqlite, how do you open that in browser? by using a base64 uri? this is not the answer to your problem. check out this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: @xiaoyi: The filesystem API is not supported by the android browser :/ Do you know any other alternatives to using a base64 uri?

Comment: @ChristianV: Sorry, I don't think so.

Comment: Are you running into a separate quota? are you handling onExceededDatabaseQuota?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be any size limitation problems when using the sqlite database. No exception is thrown...

Comment: The lack of a quota on SQLLite looks like a bug to me - I expect it will be resolved in a later version of Android.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider PhoneGap for creating a Native application, thereby bypassing quotas. That way you can continue to use HTML5 to create the app.

This blog entry suggests a way to lift quota limits for PhoneGap apps:

http://blog.mattray.info/2011/08/into-blender-javascript-sqlite-ios-and.html

Comment: That would be the best solution, but unfortunately the customer don't want to distribute the application via android market...

Answer (score 0):

You could read the PDF in chunks (asking the server to send over bytes xx to yy), to minimize the impact on the mobile system, and store that in an sqlite table with a tracking number (chunk x of y) until you have everything. Then you could rebuild at any time the whole file as a big blob, and save that blob to a temp file -- see the link above for filesystem from html5rocks.

Comment: That is not possible since I don't have access to the Android's filesystem. (the filesystem API is not supported in the android browser). It doesn't seem to be any problem saving the data into the database but rather to display it/make the browser download it as a file. It works with small files around 100k but for larger files (>2mb) the browser freezes and quits. I think the problem is the way I am trying to display the file now, using a "data:uri" approach, by creating a html <a href.. that links to the base64 encoded pdf file...